# Running PowerShell script from Python not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, subprocess

I am trying to run PowerShell script `test_me.ps1`, which takes 3 arguments: `-Name name`, `-Age age`, `-Place place`.

`input_data` is what I am passing from my pytest.

Here is my code:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.call(
        [
            "powershell.exe",
            "-Name" + input_data['name'],
            "-Age" + input_data['age'],
            "Place" + input_data['place']
        ], '&{. "./test_me.ps1"}')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    print "subprocess CalledProcessError.output = " + e.output
print output
```

I want to check output.

Comment: What output do you expect? What do you get? What do you get if you don't catch the error and potentially hide parts of it?

Comment: What is the output of test_me.ps1 when you run it in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something along the lines of:

```
output = subprocess.call(
    [
        "powershell",
        "-File", "./test_me.ps1",
        "-Name", input_data['name'], 
        "-Age", input_data['age'], 
        "Place", input_data['place']
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you just tried to output the exception Error while you wont get any because the python file you tried to run is not getting any error.

---

**Check how the logic applies**

I think you can accomplish it by returning data from the main python file and then getting it on a file to read from this script.